# AHP Priorities and Probabilities

Tags: probability

I am playing around with AHP and have calculated some priorities for a series of criteria and alternatives.  Does anyone know if it is possible to convert these into probabilities?

Thank you

Comment: As I understand it (possibly not well), AHP is a way to convert a collection of user specified valuations  into a prioritization scheme for a set of projects. If that is, at least roughly, correct then...what probabilities would you want to compute?

Comment: Thank you.  I am looking for the probability of each alternative occurring with respect to the goal.  The only data I have is the AHP stuff.

Comment: Well, as I say, my understanding is pretty vague.  I thought AHP handed you a priority scheme.  I don't see where probabilities enter into it.  Don't think I'm going to be of much help.

Comment: Thank you anyway. I'm trying to use it as input to conditional probability tables.